wireshark asterix cat062/ category062
which filter do I use to filter out only cat062 asterix messages in wireshark?
I have tried asterix.category == 062 . But it did not work. No messages are being displayed. The messages are being sent through udp socket. I have been trying to use python script also to capture the messages, again nothing is being displayed.
